Sylius is not recognising the doctrine attribute overrides
I am overriding the column "id" of the Zone entity of Sylius with "zone_id" using the following Doctrine file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="App\Entity\Addressing\Zone" table="zones">
        <attribute-overrides>
            <attribute-override name="id" type="integer">
                <field column="zone_id" />
            </attribute-override>
        </attribute-overrides>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

The relevant entity code is:
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity\Addressing;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Zone as BaseZone;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="zones")
 */
class Zone extends BaseZone
{   
    protected $zone_id;
    
    public function getZoneId()
    {
        return $this->zone_id;
    }

    public function setZoneId($zone_id)
    {
        $this->zone_id = $zone_id;
    }
    
}

When i add a product to the cart, Sylius gives the following error:
Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "App\Entity\Addressing\Zone"
It looks like it is not seeing column "zone_id". I'm using Sylius 1.13.
The full trace is:
RuntimeException
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Utility/PersisterHelper.php (line 110)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php :: getTypeOfColumn (line 817)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php -> walkSelectClause (line 552)
in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Doctrine/ORM/SqlWalker/OrderByIdentifierSqlWalker.php -> walkSelectStatement (line 34)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/TreeWalkerChain.php -> walkSelectStatement (line 97)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php -> walkSelectStatement (line 388)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php -> parse (line 274)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php -> parse (line 286)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php -> _doExecute (line 1212)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php -> executeIgnoreQueryCache (line 1166)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php -> execute (line 901)
in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Doctrine/ORM/ShippingMethodRepository.php -> getResult (line 43)
in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Component/Core/Resolver/EligibleDefaultShippingMethodResolver.php -> findEnabledForChannel (line 66)
in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Component/Core/Resolver/EligibleDefaultShippingMethodResolver.php -> getShippingMethods (line 49)
in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Component/Core/OrderProcessing/OrderShipmentProcessor.php -> getDefaultShippingMethod (line 75)
in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Component/Core/OrderProcessing/OrderShipmentProcessor.php -> createNewOrderShipment (line 63)
in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Component/Order/Processor/CompositeOrderProcessor.php -> process (line 37)
CompositeOrderProcessor->process()
in src/Component/Order/Modifier/OrderModifier.php (line 53)
     */    public function addToOrder(OrderInterface $order, OrderItemInterface $item): void    {        $this->resolveOrderItem($order, $item);                $this->orderProcessor->process($order);        foreach($order->getPromotions() as $promotion){            $this->promotionApplicator->revert($order, $promotion);        }    }
OrderModifier->addToOrder()
in src/Controller/OrderItemController.php (line 175)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php -> addAction (line 181)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php -> handleRaw (line 76)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php -> handle (line 197)

I'd appreciate any help or pointers to understanding why the column zone_id is not seen by Sylius. Is there some configuration I am missing and should know about? Thanks
